# Is there any identifying or non-Identifying relationship in this ERD?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

This is my first time learning ERD and I want to make sure whether such a relationship diagram is correct. Is there any identifying or non-Identifying relationship in this ERD?
[PatientReferral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhBUM.png)

It feels like something is missing and I need someone to check it for me.